How to format date value in gregorian format in Excel; the build in format function is not working on it

I have a column of Dates in Excel which I want to convert to Days i.e. Sunday, Saturday etc.
The Excel inbuilt formatter is not reading dates in this format and hence I'm unable to convert them Days.
Any suggestions?

If you use Text To Columns and convert those textual dates to true dates then you could easily convert them to days i.e. the excel will read those as numbers and using formatting it will show as per your preference. Presently its formatted as text. Also if using MS365 using a formula it would be simpler --> =--(A1:A3) which will convert to number and then format them as per you like.  It does work in MS365

It's probably stored as text, so convert it to a date using DATEVALUE, then use the TEXT function to do whatever you want with it. e.g. use...
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(A1),"m/d/yy")

...to get 7/12/23
Or just leave it as a date serial and format the cell to display it however you'd like it to appear. Here are both approaches...

Lastly, if neither of those work, you may have a regional date value setting on your PC causing an issue. A strategy for getting around that: Add a new sheet and list the 12 months' 3-letter abbreviations along with their corresponding month numbers...

The use a vlookup on the left-most 3 letters of your serial...
=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A1:B12, 2, False)

...and rebuild a date string, converted to a date value, from there. e.g...
=DATEVALUE(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1,3),Sheet2!A1:B12,2,FALSE) & "/" & TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,5,3),",","")) &"/" & RIGHT(A1,2))

That works by isolating the month string, converting it to a number, adding the day number (stripping out commas and spaces) and finishing it off with the last two digits of the year.

Thanks John! This throws #VALUE! error for some reason on my excel.

Strange - what is the exact text of that first date?

Ex: Jul 18, 2023

I have even tried this on MS365, still the same error.

Strange... =DATEVALUE("Jul 12, 2023")  gives me the date serial (45119). Your regional date value settings may be causing the issue, as described here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-datevalue-text-issue-with-regional-settings/d6d94c5b-c07a-4981-8a98-a217fb269eb2  I'll augment my answer above with a third approach.

Thanks everyone! I was able to do this by using Text to Column feature.
